# mysql_error() is not working, when using mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysqli

No error showing using mysql_error() function. msqli_query() is working fine but when i add mysql_error beside it, i receive nothing in web page even thou the query is invalid and connection is wrong.

```
example. mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysql_error()); <--- Nothing comes up
```

link script:

```
<?php

#SET DATABASE CREDENTIALS
$mysql_host     = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'root';
$mysql_password = 'root';
$mysql_db   = 'attendance';
$mysql_error    = 'Error: connection';

//TEST CONNECTION
$link = mysqli_connect( $mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_db) or die($mysql_error);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{

printf("Connection Failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();

}
?>
```

Query Script:

```
<?php

require('conn.php'); <--- **No Problem**

$query = "SELsECT * FROM `$TBL` WHERE `textFromDate` >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($date1)."' AND `textToDate` <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($date2)."' AND `Scheme`='Paid'";

$resultwholeday = mysqli_query($link, $wholeday) or die(mysql_error()); <--- **might have problem**


?>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `mysqli_error()`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

As far as I know (I may be wrong), every mysql_* function has a relative mysqli_* function.  They do not work as substitutes.

**EDIT (addressing comment):**

According to PHP.net's `mysqli_error()` docs, it requires one argument to be passed:

`string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`

This mysqli $link that you are passing will be the variable that contains your database connection information.  So you create a mysqli connection and save it to $link.  Then run some queries.  `mysqli_error($link)` will find the *last* error that has occurred on $link (or the mysqli connection).

Comment: heres my code. $query = "SELsECT * FROM `$WholedayTBL` WHERE `textFromDate` >= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($date1)."' AND `textToDate` <= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($date2)."' AND `Scheme`='Paid'";
$resultwholeday = mysqli_query($link, $wholeday) or die(mysqli_error($wholeday));
I received a lot of error just like this  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `mysqli_error`, not `mysql_error`, when you call MySQLi APIs. Same with `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, I changed my code already in that way. i receive this error. Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\upload\exercise-files\final\Process.php on line 32

Comment: You need to provide it the link resource in first parameter. `mysqli_error($link)`

Comment: Glad its solved, but the answer was given by @Jeremy Roman, so thank him :)